# What is the difference between the Intel XDK watchAcceleration method and the same-named Cordova method?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, accelerometer, intel-xdk

What exactly is the difference between the Intel XDK [watchAcceleration](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/492838) method, and the [same-named method](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#accelerometer.watchAcceleration) offered by Apache Cordova?

Does one have better performance than the other? And is it better to use these or just use the native JavaScript [DeviceMotion event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceMotionEvent.acceleration)?

Answer (score 1):

There is one subtle difference, the XDK version will attempt to "preserve" your X and Y orientation, whereas the Cordova does not. Thus, you may see different numbers from each when you compare the outputs (one might give negative numbers where the other gives positive numbers), depending on whether you retrieve the accelerometer numbers in portrait or landscape orientation.

Other than that, there is no significant difference between the two. You should use only one, not both, in an application.

From a performance perspective, they are identical.

Regarding the Mozilla reference, I don't believe that API is available in most webviews. If it is available, this would be the preferred API, but where it is not available you need to fall back on either the Cordova or XDK solution.

Comment: I just checked on Android 4.4 webview (which has an updated webview based on the Chrome Mobile browser, rather than the older Android browser) and it does not include these APIs. Note, that it does have a DeviceMotionEvent object, but the APIs are not there.

Comment: the webview has DevicMotionEvent are you sure ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It *is* present in the webview of newer Android devices (4.x) and iOS devices. It is not present on Win 8 Phone devices.